# ¿Cómo almacenar resultados numéricos en una nueva lista?

Tags: python, lista, iteradores, almacenamiento

Estoy queriendo construir una nueva lista a partir de los resultados que vaya arrojando la función que he construido pero no encuentro la manera, recién estoy empezando a programar.
Tengo que encontrar el valor más cercano a 0, y mi intención es ingresar por un lado la lista, y por otro lado el valor al que me quiero acercar. Que cada valor de la lista reste con el valor al que me quiero acercar, y cada resultado se almacene en una nueva lista.

Esto me devuelve los valores sueltos, uno debajo del otro. He probado hacer "print(list(result))" pero me devuelve "'int' object is not iterable". Entiendo que debería crear una lista nueva "nl = []" e ir almacenando ahí los resultados, pero no logro hacerlo.

```
ts1 = [1, -2, -8, 4, 5]
ts2 = []
ts3 = [-5, -4, -2, 12, -40, 4, 2, 18, 11, 5]
nl = []

def closest_to_zero(array, value):
    for i in array:
        result = i - value
        print(result)

closest_to_zero(ts1, 0)
```

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: ¡Gracias por la indicación y la lectura recomendada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar la función `min()` en conjunto con un `lambda` para hacerlo

```
def closest_to_zero(array, value):
    return min(array, key=lambda x:abs(x-value))

ts1 = [1, -2, -8, 4, 5]
print(closest_to_zero(ts1, 0))
```

Esto devuelve `1`

Y al probarlo con `ts3`

```
ts3 = [-5, -4, -2, 12, -40, 4, 2, 18, 11, 5]
print(closest_to_zero(ts3, 0))
```

Devuelve `-2`

**Nota:** A pesar que `-2` y `2` serían soluciones válidas se muestra `-2` porque es el primer elemento que aparece.

**Edición:** Como bien comentó CandidMoe, si se busca únicamente encontrar el valor más cercano a cero bastaría con `abs(x)`

```
def closest_to_zero(array, value):
    return min(array, key=lambda x:abs(x))
```

Pero en caso de querer renombrar la función y utilizarla para encontrar el valor más cercano a cualquier número podría funcionar de la siguiente forma:

```
def closest_to_num(array, value):
    return min(array, key=lambda x:abs(x-value))

ts3 = [-5, -4, -2, 12, -40, 4, 2, 18, 11, 5]
closest_to_num(ts3, 10)
```

Esto devuelve `11`

Comment: Basta con `abs(x)`.

Comment: Si, pero como la función del OP tiene un segundo argumento `value` pensé que en un futuro querría utilizarla para aproximar a cualquier otro valor, por eso lo había puesto así

Comment: Toda la razón ...

Comment: No me alcanzan las palabras para agradecerles. Ahora a leer y procesar bien lo que me han comentado para entenderlo. Gracias por su tiempo. Cualquier cosa si puedo les pregunto algo más por acá, ¿así funciona?

Comment: Buen día, si hay dudas del código podrías poner comentarios, si hay preguntas adicionales lo mejor es crear una nueva publicación, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). De esa forma te puedes familiarizar con los lineamientos del sitio. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Rodrigo. Creo que lo que buscas hacer es lo siguiente

```
ts1 = [1, -2, -8, 4, 5]
ts2 = []
ts3 = [-5, -4, -2, 12, -40, 4, 2, 18, 11, 5]
nl = []

def closest_to_zero(array, value):
    for i in array:
        result = i - value
        nl.append(result) # append es el metodo de una lista para añadir valores
        print(result)

closest_to_zero(ts1, 0)
```

Luego para encontrar el valor mas cercano, buscarias el valor minimo de la nueva lista eso lo puedes hacer con

```
min(nl)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Creo que entendiste muy bien lo que estaba buscando. Probé con tu código copiando y pegando y me devuelve lo mismo que antes. Es decir, los valores que devuelve la función los imprime uno debajo del otro en consola, en vez de imprimir una lista, sobre la cual quisiera aplicar min(nl).

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es guardar e imprimir todos los números que están a la distancia mínima:

**1. Calcular la distancia mínima**

```
def mas_proximo_a_valor(arr: list, valor=0):
    #   Cargar una lista con la diferencia
    #   entre cada número de la lista y el valor.
    lista_de_distancias = []
    for n in arr:
        lista_de_distancias.append(abs(n-valor))

    #   Calcular el valor mínimo de la lista.
    minimo = min(lista_de_distancias)
```

Con comprension de listas queda:

```
def mas_proximo_a_valor(arr: list, valor=0):
    minimo = min([abs(n-valor) for n in arr])
```

**2. Cargar una lista con los números a la distancia mínima**

```
    #   Cargar una lista con los números a la distancia mínima
    num_con_minima_distancia = []
    for n in arr:
        if abs(n - valor) == minimo:
            num_con_minima_distancia.append((str(n)))

    #   Los valores se pueden repetir, para evitarlo lo pasamos a un set()
    num_con_minima_distancia = set(num_con_minima_distancia)

    #   Pasarlo a cadena formateada
    num_con_minima_distancia = ', '.join(num_con_minima_distancia)
```

Podría quedar así:

```
    num_con_minima_distancia = ', '.join( { str(n) for n in arr if abs(n-valor) == minimo} )
```

Devolver los dos datos:

```
    return minimo, num_con_minima_distancia
```

**Código completo:**

```
def mas_proximo_a_valor(arr: list, valor=0):
    #   Cargar una lista con la diferencia
    #   entre cada número de la lista y el valor.
    lista_de_distancias = []
    for n in arr:
        lista_de_distancias.append(abs(n-valor))

    #   Calcular el valor mínimo de la lista.
    minimo = min(lista_de_distancias)

    #   Cargar una lista con los números a la distancia mínima
    num_con_minima_distancia = []
    for n in arr:
        if abs(n - valor) == minimo:
            num_con_minima_distancia.append((str(n)))

    #   Los valores se pueden repetir, para evitarlo lo pasamos a un set()
    num_con_minima_distancia = set(num_con_minima_distancia)

    #   Pasarlo a cadena formateada
    num_con_minima_distancia = ', '.join(num_con_minima_distancia)

    return minimo, num_con_minima_distancia
```

**Con comprensión de listas**

```
def mas_proximo_a_valor(arr: list, valor=0):
    minimo = min([abs(n-valor) for n in arr])
    return minimo, ', '.join( { str(n) for n in arr if abs(n-valor) == minimo} )
```

[Info sobre comprension de listas](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
.

Comment: Muchas gracias Tomy. Ahora me dedico a entender bien lo que me dijiste para poder responderte.

Comment: Edito y añado explicación del código